# Serverless Framework AWS Lambda Version Duplicate Problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

Every time I deploy to aws with serverless framework, a new version is added, how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can prevent duplicate versions by using this plugin.

[serverless-prune-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-prune-plugin)